# display inline-block still breaks line in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, css

Heloo.

I have problem with multiple DIV elements in google chrome. if those have display:inline-block, sometimes chrome still keeps breaking line. Everything works fine in Firefox, Opera and IE, but not in chrome.

try visiting this page:
http://tridex.pl/kategoria/%2A00/Nowosci.html?typ_listy=4

This is shop. There are 2 similar item layout styles, one with 3 items in row, one with "as many as will fit on your screen" in row. Everything works as it should in Firefox, IE, Opera... but Chrome displays 2 items in first line and 3 in each another.

Layout is modified on the fly, so maybe this is the problem? But since it works in all other browsers, why it does not in Chrome? Should i call something to tell Chrome to recalculate DIV width and rearrage those?

Does anyone have any idea how does it work in Chrome? Is there something else i should

Answer (score 1):

Setting the width style of the parent element a bit wider helped me, looks like the elements need more room in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work for me in Firefox either... however this seems to be the issue.

```
<div id="prawy_div" style="width: 564px; left: 273px; position: relative;">
```

If I change its width to what it starts out as... 680px, Everything looks fine. A script is changing it for some reason, and boy does it want to change it... seems to be attached to your scroll event.